# Able to deploy website for production on neither Netlify nor Vercel

Tags: node.js, npm

```
Cloning github.com/Chandraprakash-Darji/Order-Summary-Component-FM (Branch: master, Commit: 8425b91)
Cloning completed: 349.228ms
Analyzing source code...
Installing build runtime...
Build runtime installed: 2.635s
Looking up build cache...
Build Cache not found
Detected package.json
Installing dependencies...
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-64@0.13.15: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-02-08T09_30_31_098Z-debug.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

My repo I am trying to deploy: https://github.com/Chandraprakash-Darji/Order-Summary-Component-FM

I am using Vite to build my site.